# What's the benefit of sinking ships in Battlefield 1942?

Tags: battlefield-1942

I've dug it up again and remember that you can sink enemy ships on some maps. I've tried a few times but it's a lot of work so my question is: Is it worth the effort?

Sure it removes a spawn point but unless you manage to take out all ships the bots will just spawn somewhere else.

So does it incur some significant ticket loss, to make it worth it?

Also this question is mainly aimed at single-player where I don't have X teammates to coordinate with...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is to prevent the enemy access to airplanes and a mobile spawn point. Since its single player, the AI isn't smart enough to move the ships or use the guns/planes very effectively.

Answer (score 0):

To deny the enemy team use of spawn points, landing craft, and ship-based weaponry.

Its generally less useful (and easier) in single player but the AI can pull off some insane shots with ship-based MGs and AA sometimes, so if you're intent on flying it can still be a good idea depending on the map.

If you're defending on a map like Wake Island or Iwo Jima then sinking a ship means the enemy can really only come from one direction and not two, which makes the job of defending easier.